# Apache - подвисают запросы с IP

Tags: apache2

Столкнулся с проблемой: время от времени сервер (Apache2) блокирует запросы клиентов по IP. При попытке открыть сайт - недоступен, в то же время он без проблем открывается с других IP. Такая блокировка длится неопределенное время: может 3 минуты, может 20, и потом сама "исчезает". Блокируются клиенты с различных IP.

Если перезагрузить Apcache - доступ с IP сразу возобновляется. Когда к сайту нет доступа, все остальные сервисы (не Apache) для клиента - доступны.

Подскажите, в сторону каких настроек Apache смотреть?

Comment: Может fail2ban работает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fail2ban

Comment: Нет - блокируется только доступ к Апачу, только с конкретного ИП и на неопределенное время 3-20мин.